# JPA MySQL Connection in Java EE project

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I am running a local MySQL Server, later I want to use one on a remote computer and I have a question how to setup JPA in my Java EE project correctly.

First of all, do I have to setup the database connection in my application server or only in my persistence.xml? I have just added it in a JBoss Server and I can use JNDI now. But JNDI is not compatible with JPA, is it correct?

I tried it now with Geronimo and JBoss, with both I am not sure what I have to do correctly. I wanted to use OpenJPA as an JPA implementation which is standard on Geronimo.

I found many tutorials on the web, but most isnt very complet.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="schulungen" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
        <jta-data-source>MySQLServer</jta-data-source>
        <class>model.Schulung</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

What is JTA-Data-Source? If I understood it right, it's a name given by the application server to identify the which connection I want.

Do I have to add properties like jdbc connection URL etc.?

I hope you understand my problem.

Comment: Yes you have to setup the database connection in your jboss application server. an entry in standalone.xml needs to be done.

Comment: And how looks the persistence.xml in this case? And do I need to configure it there or is it possible to do this in the persistence.xml too without touching the application server?

Comment: <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/KitchensinkrfDS" pool-name="KitchensinkrfDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>**connection url**</connection-url>
                    <driver>**driver in my case h2**</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>sa</user-name>
                        <password>sa</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>. Some what like this , configuration is different for oracle Xadatasource needs to be defined in standalone.

Comment: This is the standalone.xml, right? But how looks the persistence.xml in my web project?